# Alternative style to passing a block to a method?

Tags: ruby

What is it called when you pass a block to a method in this way: `.map(&:capitalize)`?

Is it just syntactic sugar? Shorthand? Can you do anything else with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every method in Ruby has a special "block" slot that isn't a normal argument. This is because passing precisely one block to a method is the most common use case and Ruby optimizes it¹. The `&` symbol is used to denote the passing of something specifically inside that slot.

```
def with_regular_argument(block)
  block.call
end

def with_block_argument(&block)
  block.call
end

with_regular_argument lambda { puts 'regular' }    # regular
with_block_argument { puts 'block argument' }      # block argument
```

The symbol can also be used when calling methods. That way, you can pass any object as the block, and `to_proc` will be called on it in order to coerce it to a `Proc`.

```
def to_proc
  proc { puts 'the main object was converted to a Proc!' }
end

with_block_argument &self    # the main object was converted to a Proc!
```

Note that the coercion would not have been performed had you invoked `with_regular_argument`:

```
begin
  with_regular_argument self
rescue => error
  puts error.message            # undefined method `call' for main:Object
end
```

The `Symbol` class implements `to_proc`. It basically works like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc { |receiver| receiver.send self }
  end
end
```

So, how does the following line work?

```
enumerable.map &:to_s
```

1. We are passing `:to_s` in the special block slot. This is denoted by the `&`.
2. The use of `&` calls `to_proc` on the symbol.
3. `to_proc` returns a `Proc` that sends `:to_s` to the first argument.
4. This `Proc` is then passed to the `map` method in the special block slot.
5. Every element yielded becomes the receiver of the message.

It is pretty much equivalent to:

```
enumerable.map { |receiver| receiver.send :to_s }
```

---

¹ Yehuda Katz. **Ruby is NOT a Callable Oriented Language** (It’s Object Oriented). [Blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/21/ruby-is-not-a-callable-oriented-language/).